# Cron vs. Python ‘schedule’ for scheduling tasks with Flask

Tags: python, cron

I’m looking to implement a script that calls a web API at regular intervals (e.g. every hour). I’m using Flask as my server.

Should I use the Cron framework, or is it better to use Python’s [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) function to run the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron, otherwise you'll need something extra to make sure your python script is always running.  Of course, this counts for cron too.

Comment: How would one initiate a scheduled task with Cron, other than manually starting the Cron schedule from the command line?

Comment: That's the init systems job, good old sysvinit or bad new systemd.